# Invalid Object Passes Schema Validation

Tags: node.js, meteor, simple-schema

In a meteor app I've been getting my feet wet with [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) lately. I've built the below mentioned pretty simple schema :-)

However, when I try to validate an **invalidate entry** (say one where `entry.link.url` ist not a valid URL or one where `entry.link.project` is `undefined`) against that schema via `entrySchema.validate()` the validation does not work properly, i.e. the invalid entry passes the validation whereas I would expect it to fail.

```
let entrySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  link: {
    type: Object
  },
  'link.project': {
    type: String //this validation does not work!
  },
  'link.url': {
    type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url //this validation does not work!
  }
});
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing here?

Comment: Which validation you are talking about,
 type : String? 
can you explain more that what values are permitted in link. project.

Comment: Also take care about SimpleSchema as it's current status is build failing

Comment: hey mehta-rohan. I think I found the error. It should be `regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url` and `type: String` - duh! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Do you want to post that as the answer, so that I can give credit to you?

Comment: pleasure, sir :)